# Background Image Behind the ApplicationBar

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am loading an image on my page using

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/kisses.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
...
```

This works great except for one thing. I'd like to use the same image as the splash screen and when the app is loaded and the splash screen goes away and the page background loads, I want the transition to be visually seamless. As it is, the image fills all 800 vertical pixels for when it's a splash screen and only (800 - ApplicationBarHeight) when it's a page background.
So I figured it was because I have it behind the LayoutGrid instead of behind the PhoneApplicationPage. But when I try to put it behind the PhoneApplicationPage (and make the LayoutGrid transparent) it doesn't work. Here's what I'm trying. Why doesn't this work?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Images/kisses.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Background>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should load the image in the LayoutRoot and set the opacity of the ApplicationBar to 99% - this way the image should be rendered with the full height / behind the AppBar.

Cannot test it myself at the moment, but if it doesn't work I will take a second look when I'm back in front of a PC :)

Answer (score 1):

2 steps:
(1)
in
 **`<phone:PhoneApplicationPage`** 
set    **shell:SystemTray.IsVisible = "False"**

---

(2)

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
<Grid.Background>
<ImageBrush ImageSource="Assets/Images/Flowers.png"></ImageBrush>
</Grid.Background>
```